# JPARepository's findAll query on baseclass of @MappedSuperClass just returns entries of baseclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA MappedSuperClass like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Foo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {       
private Status status;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private User owner;
```

And two subclasses inheriting from Foo, namely defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BARFOO")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
public @Data class Bar extends Foo {
  private String beer;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BLUBFOO")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
public @Data class Blub extends Foo {
private String cider;
```

Now when I save some data in an Object of type Bar or Blub I expect a myRepository.findAll to actually return cider or beer AND both status and owner from the MappedSuperClass. Instead, it just returns cider or beer - the properties of the subclass.

Is there just an error in my reasoning or am I missing on anything completely?

This is my BarRepository:

```
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Long> { 
}
```

And this is how findAll() in my BarService is "implemented":

```
@Inject
private BarRepository barRepository;
public Iterable<Bar> findAll() {
  return barRepository.findAll();
}
```

I also have both for my Blub subclass. Any hint is appreciated and when I missed on any best practice, I'd be glad if you put me on the right track again.

Comment: So, what does it do instead? The fields are null? What is there in the database?

Comment: I created for instance a new owner which is a User object and used
    `Bar.setOwner(owner)` and connecting to the database myself shows me that JPA creates one big table with all the column names of Foo and Bar. And there is a **1** inside the owner_id column. Nevertheless `findAll()` just returns the columns of **Bar**. How do I access all the column values?

Comment: bar.getStatus(), and bar.getOwner(). Show us the Java code used to get the Bar instances, and the code used to access the information and make your diagnostic.

Comment: Something is wrong from what you've described if you are getting 1 big table instead of "BLUBFOO" and "BARFOO" tables.  Is what you described correct, or could other files/mapppings be being picked up and used somehow?  What values are you inserting for cider+beer, and are they inserted correctly as well as user?  Try removing the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn unless it is needed for something not shown, such as a secondary table.